# matplotlib/pandas: put line label along the plotted lines in time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting time series data comparing system characteristics from multiple nodes. I want to label the line from a particular node explicitly along its line. So far I have succeeded in putting separate line style for the particular node, which gives it distinctive line and  distinctive style marker in the legend box.

I am trying to find a way to put distinctive label along the line, possibly text curving along the line. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text curving along the line isn't easy to do with matplotlib, but `annotate` will allow you to easily label the line with text and an arrow.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 200)
y = np.cos(x) + 0.5 * np.sin(3 * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.annotate(r'$y = cos(x) + \frac{sin(3x)}{2}$', xy=(x[70], y[70]), 
            xytext=(20, 10), textcoords='offset points', va='center',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was aware of annotate but was planning to use it to point important phases in time. I will now play with annotate to achieve the goal sought in this post. Hurdle will be to figure out programmatically a point in the specific line where it is separate from other lines.